# Raspberry Pi C++ Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi

I have some code written in C++ and when I compile it on my laptop, the results show, however, I have tried to compile and run the code onto the RPI and I get the error:

> Segmentation fault

How the program (currently) works:

- Reads in a (.wav) file into a vector of doubles ("rawData")
- Splits the rawData into blocks (blockked)

The segmentation fault happens when I try and split the data into blocks. The sizes:

rawData - 57884
blockked - 112800

Now I know the RPI only has 256MB and this could possibly be the problem, or, i'm not handling the data properly. I have included some code as well, to help demonstrate how things are running:

(main.cpp):

```
int main()
{
int N = 600;
int M = 200;

float sumthresh = 0.035;
float zerocorssthres = 0.060;

Wav sampleWave;

if(!sampleWave.readAudio("repositry/example.wav", DOUBLE))
{
    cout << "Cannot open the file BOOM";

}

// Return the data
vector<double> rawData = sampleWave.returnRaw();
// THIS segments (typedef vector<double> iniMatrix;)
vector<iniMatrix> blockked = sampleWave.something(rawData, N, M);


cout << rawData.size();

return EXIT_SUCCESS;   
}
```

(function: something)

```
int n = theData.size();
int maxblockstart = n - N;
int lastblockstart = maxblockstart - (maxblockstart % M);

int numblocks = (lastblockstart)/M + 1;
vector< vector<double> > subBlock;
vector<double> temp;
this->width = N;
this->height = numblocks;

subBlock.resize(600*187);
for(int i=0; (i < 600); i++)
{
    subBlock.push_back(vector<double>());
    for(int j=0; (j < 187); j++)
    {   
        subBlock[i].push_back(theData[i*N+j]);
    } 
}    
return subBlock;
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated :)! Hopefully this is enough description.

Comment: `theData[i*N+j]` looks suspicious. Also `subBlock.resize(600*187);` seems to be an error. You are not creating 2-d array here, but 1-d.

Comment: You're also using push_back in the loop, which means you have a bunch of empty `vector<double>`, then adding on to that

Comment: Thank you for both of your replies. @Collin I do see the empty vector<double>'s that you mentioned. I might re-consider how i'd re-write the code. Quick question though.. Why does it work on my laptop, but, not on the RPI?

Comment: It's likely you're invoking undefined behavior somewhere. As @Lol4t0 pointed out, probably where you access `theData[i*N+j]`. It appears you do a bunch of checking to make sure that won't happen, then throw it all out and loop over some constants. Different compilers on different systems will not work in different ways. It probably only appears to work on your laptop.

Comment: @Collin Thank you :)! I will work on this, do you have any suggestions on how I should do it differently than theData[i*N+j]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably overrunning an array somewhere (Maybe not even in the code you posted). I'm not really sure what you're trying to do with the blocking either, but I guess you want to split your wave file into 600 sample chunks?

If so, I think you want something more like the following:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>>
SimpleWav::something(const std::vector<double>& data, int N) {

    //How many blocks of size N can we get?
    int num_blocks = data.size() / N;

    //Create the vector with enough empty slots for num_blocks blocks
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> blocked(num_blocks);

    //Loop over all the blocks
    for(int i = 0; i < num_blocks; i++) {
        //Resize the inner vector to fit this block            
        blocked[i].resize(N);

        //Pull each sample for this block
        for(int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            blocked[i][j] = data[i*N + j];
        }
    }

    return blocked;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much :)! Should it just be producing 96 blocks? And yes, 600 chunks but they should overlap sometimes.

Comment: This is what I got in the tutorial: This function separates the vector into blocks.  Each block has size N. and consecutive blocks differ in their starting positions by M Typically N = 30 msec (600 samples) M = 10 msec (200 samples).. There are 600 samples in each of the blocks, and, have different start positions.. So to me, everything looks good!